# Row expansion via "*" is not supported here

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm in a trigger context and trying to get following snippet to work.

```
execute format('insert into %I (user_name, action, new_values, query) 
    values (''%I'', ''i'', hstore(($1).*), current_query())', 
     tg_table_name::text || '_audit', current_user::text)
using new;
```

I'm getting the following error

> ```
> [SQL]insert into book (title, n_pages) values ('PG is Great', 250);
>
> [Err] ERROR:  row expansion via "*" is not supported here
> LINE 2: values ('u1', 'i', hstore(($1).*), current_q...
>                                                ^
> QUERY:  insert into book_audit (user_name, action, new_values, query) 
>         values ('u1', 'i', hstore(($1).*), current_query())
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "if_modified_func" line 8 at EXECUTE statement
> ```

Any suggestion on how to fix **row expansion via "*" is not supported here** ?
Coupling to specific schema is not an option.

Comment: The non hstore which works execute format('insert into %I select ''i'', now(), 
          user, ($1).*', tg_table_name || '_audit') using new;
        return new;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top of my head, it should work like this:

```
EXECUTE format('
   INSERT INTO %I (user_name, action, new_values, query) 
   SELECT $1, ''i'', $2, current_query()'
   , tg_table_name::text || '_audit')
USING current_user, hstore(NEW);
```

It is better to supply all values with the `USING` clause.
And you can [cast a record to hstore directly with `hstore(record)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE).