# Robust approach for building SQL queries programmatically

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have to resort to raw SQL where the ORM is falling short (using Django 1.7). The problem is that most of the queries end up being 80-90% similar. I cannot figure out a robust & secure way to build queries without violating re-usability.

Is string concatenation the only way out, i.e. build parameter-less query strings using `if-else` conditions, then safely include the parameters using prepared statements (to avoid SQL injection). I want to follow a simple approach for templating SQL for my project instead of re-inventing a mini ORM.

For example, consider this query:

```
SELECT id, name, team, rank_score
FROM
  ( SELECT id, name, team
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team
                       ORDER BY count_score DESC) AS rank_score
    FROM 
      (SELECT id, name, team
       COUNT(score) AS count_score
       FROM people
       INNER JOIN scores on (scores.people_id = people.id)
       GROUP BY id, name, team
      ) AS count_table
  ) AS rank_table
WHERE rank_score < 3
```

How can I:

a) add optional `WHERE` constraint on `people` **or**
b) change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER` **or**
c) change `COUNT` to `SUM` **or**
d) completely skip the `OVER / PARTITION` clause?

Comment: Not with Django - but I ended up creating a dictionary based approach, where the various dictionaries defined the data, and the relationships between tables. Is there a way that you can add data to the Django models - or even better create a mixin which create your queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Better query

Fix the syntax, simplify and clarify:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT p.person_id, p.name, p.team, sum(s.score)::int AS score
        , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY p.team ORDER BY sum(s.score) DESC)::int AS rnk
    FROM  person p
    JOIN  score  s USING (person_id)
    GROUP BY 1
   ) sub
WHERE  rnk < 3;
```

Building on my updated table layout. See fiddle below.

You do not need the additional subquery. Window functions are executed *after* aggregate functions, so you can nest it like demonstrated.

While talking about "rank", you probably want to use `rank()`, not `row_number()`.

Assuming `people.people_id` is the PK, you can simplify the `GROUP BY` clause.

Be sure to table-qualify all column names that might be ambiguous.

### PL/pgSQL function

I would write a PL/pgSQL function that takes parameters for your variable parts. Implementing `a` - `c` of your points. `d` is unclear, leaving that for you to add.

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  person_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, name text NOT NULL
, team text
);

CREATE TABLE score (
  score_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, person_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES person
, score int NOT NULL
);

-- dummy values
WITH ins AS (
   INSERT INTO person(name, team)
   SELECT 'Jon Doe ' || p, t
   FROM   generate_series(1,20) p                   -- 20 guys x
        , unnest ('{team1,team2,team3}'::text[]) t  -- 3 teams
   RETURNING person_id
   )
INSERT INTO score(person_id, score)
SELECT i.person_id, (random() * 100)::int
FROM   ins i, generate_series(1,5) g;               -- 5 scores each
```

Function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_demo(_agg        text DEFAULT 'sum'
                                , _left_join  bool DEFAULT false
                                , _where_name text DEFAULT null)
  RETURNS TABLE(person_id int, name text, team text, score numeric, rnk bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _agg_op  CONSTANT text[] := '{count, sum, avg}';  -- allowed agg functions
   _sql     text;
BEGIN
   -- assert --
   IF _agg ILIKE ANY (_agg_op) THEN
      -- all good
   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION '_agg must be one of %', _agg_op;
   END IF;

   -- query --
   _sql := format('
   SELECT *
   FROM  (
      SELECT p.person_id, p.name, p.team, %1$s(s.score)::numeric AS score
           , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY p.team ORDER BY %1$s(s.score) DESC) AS rnk
       FROM  person p
       %2$s  score  s USING (person_id)
       %3$s
       GROUP BY 1
      ) sub
   WHERE  rnk < 3
   ORDER  BY team, rnk'
    , _agg                                                                 -- %1$s
    , CASE WHEN _left_join THEN 'LEFT JOIN' ELSE 'JOIN' END                -- %2$s
    , CASE WHEN _where_name <> '' THEN 'WHERE p.name LIKE $1' ELSE '' END  -- %3$s
   );

   -- debug   -- inspect query first
   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;

   -- execute -- unquote when tested ok
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _sql
   USING  _where_name;   -- $1
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```sql
SELECT * FROM f_demo();
SELECT * FROM f_demo('sum', TRUE, '%2');    
SELECT * FROM f_demo('avg', FALSE);
SELECT * FROM f_demo(_where_name := '%1_'); -- named param
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4v4kCQ_I)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/93ec86/1)</sub>

- You need a firm understanding of PL/pgSQL. Else, there is too much to explain. You'll find related answers here on SO under [plpgsql](/questions/tagged/plpgsql) for every detail in the answer.
- All parameters are treated safely, no SQL injection possible. See:

  - [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)
  - [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- Note in particular, how a `WHERE` clause is added conditionally when `_where_name` is passed, with the positional parameter `$1` in the query sting. The value is passed to `EXECUTE` *as value* with the [**`USING`** clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). No type conversion, no escaping, no chance for SQL injection. Examples:

  - [Row expansion via "*" is not supported here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342652/row-expansion-via-is-not-supported-here/18351858#18351858)
  - [SQL state: 42601 syntax error at or near "11"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850194/sql-state-42601-syntax-error-at-or-near-11/11850768#11850768)
  - [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)
- Use `DEFAULT` values for function parameters, so you are free to provide any or none. More:

  - [Functions with variable number of input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782199/functions-with-variable-number-of-input-parameters/16789179#16789179)
  - [The manual on calling functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html)
- The function [**`format()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) is instrumental for building complex dynamic SQL strings in a safe and clean fashion.

Comment: Your query cleanup looks great for maintainability. Thank you for the tip. I'll read more to understand the `PL/pgSQL function` function part. Admittedly, it'll be easier for me to have the query builder in Python, since I understand that better.

Comment: @click: I added some more explanation and links.