# Dynamic FROM clause in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, dynamic-sql, window-functions

Using PostgreSQL 9.1.13 I've written the followed query to calculate some data:

```sql
WITH windowed AS (
    SELECT a.person_id, a.category_id,
        CAST(dense_rank() OVER w AS float) / COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY category_id) * 100.0 AS percentile
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (person_id, category_id) *
        FROM performances s
        -- Want to insert a FROM clause here
        INNER JOIN person p ON s.person_id = p.ident
        ORDER BY person_id, category_id, created DESC
    ) a
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY score)
)
SELECT category_id,percentile FROM windowed 
WHERE person_id = 1;
```

I now want to turn this into a stored procedure but my issue is that in the middle there, where I showed the comment, I need to place a dynamic WHERE clause.   For example, I'd like to add something like:

```sql
WHERE p.weight > 110 OR p.weight IS NULL
```

The calling application let's people pick filters and so I want to be able to pass the appropriate filters into the query.  There could be 0 or many filters, depending on the caller, but I could pass it all in as a properly formatted `where` clause as a string parameter, for example.

The calling application just sends values to a webservice, which then builds the string and calls the stored procedure, so SQL injection attacks won't really be an issue.

Comment: You can use [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg-sql-execute-immediate.html) to execute any string as an SQL query.

Comment: You can use parameters instead of passing in an SQL string, if you know all possible filters in advance. See here for some examples: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html

Comment: What you display is not a `FROM` clause but a set of `WHERE` conditions and cannot go where you indicated. For an answer in code one would need *exact* specifications of the possible `WHERE` conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The calling application just sends values to a webservice, which then
>   builds the string and calls the stored procedure, so SQL injection
>   attacks won't really be an issue.

***Too many cooks spoil the broth.***

Either let your webserive build the SQL statement **or** let Postgres do it. Don't use both on the same query. That leaves two possible weak spots for SQL injection attacks and makes debugging and maintenance a lot harder.

Here is **full code example** for a **plpgsql function** that builds and executes an SQL statement dynamically while making SQL injection impossible (just from two days ago):

- [Robust approach for building SQL queries programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186353/robust-approach-for-building-sql-queries-programmatically/25191127#comment39234916_25191127)

Details heavily depend on exact requirements.